# tap on points on touch screen with openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, mobile

I have openlayers 2.13 along with geoserver 2.1.3.

I have a vector layer where points created, after a CQL filter is activated.

I have a click event for those points. In pc/laptop works fine, but in mobiles (iphone4s safari and android vimicro firefox) if I tap with my finger a point, nothing happens.

I only load the openlayers library `<script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>` and zoom/pan on the map works in mobiles. CQL filter also works and the points are render in mobiles.

But I can not tap them.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks in advance

the code (I can provide more, if you think is neccessary):

```
mylayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("my layer", {renderers: ["Canvas", "SVG", "VML"]})

//Add a select feature control 
var select_feature_control = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(mylayer, {multiple: false,toggle: true});

map.addControl(select_feature_control);

//Activate the control 
select_feature_control.activate();

function selected_feature(event){
//do stuff
}
```

**EDIT**

I have this now , trying to use `Control.GetFeature`

```
//create layer
mylayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("mylayer", {renderers: ["Canvas", "SVG", "VML"]})

//set protocol
var myprotocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    url:  "/geoserver/wfs",
    featureType: "mylayer",
    featureNS: "http://www.mysite.gr"
});

//set control
var select_feature_control = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
  protocol: myprotocol,
  click: true,
  maxFeatures: 1,
  clickTolerance: 1,
  box: false,
  hover: false
});

//add the control
map.addControl(select_feature_control);

//activate the control
select_feature_control.activate();

//register it an connect it with the function
pins.events.register('featureselected', this, selected_feature);

//the function - gets the id by splitting the fid
function selected_feature(event){
var sf = event.feature.fid;
var sfs = sf.split(".");
var sff = sfs[1];
showtext(sff);
}
```

thats the part of the cql filter

```
//pass the filter to the layer
var prot =  new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    url:  "/geoserver/wfs",
    featureType: "mylayer",
    featureNS: "http://www.mysite.gr",
    defaultFilter: filter_final});

var _CallBack = function(resp) {
    pins.addFeatures(resp.features)
}


var response = prot.read({callback: _CallBack});


//refresh to render POIs
mylayer.refresh({force:true});
```

I can search the layer and see points on the map. But I still can not select in mobile. In pc, I can click a point, but the cursor of the mouse becomes hourglass and nothing happens. Can you spot what is wrong?

Thanks a million

Comment: Is wfs enabled on your geoserver? Does firefox/firebug or chrome developer tools give you any information? I have wfs response with one feature coming back after a click.

Comment: @Ralph Dell I went to Geoserver > Services > WFS and the "Enable WFS" is clicked. So i guess wfs is actually enabled. When I click a point on the map, in the "Network" of Chrome's console I see a POST with a status 200. But point does not get clicked and the `function selected_feature(event){` does not work. At least when using `Control.SelectFeature` works fine on pc. I tried to load other files too, `openlayers.mobile.js`, `CQL.js`, `Format.js` as neogeomat said, but no difference.

Comment: @RalphDell I also tried to use a `callback` inside a `Control.SelectFeature` and still not work in mobiles. I tried to set the index of the layer 0 or 99, still nothing....

Comment: I am sorry to say I am out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: On this page http://gis.catawbacountync.gov/temp/getfeature.html , on your tablet when you zoom in, tap the Identify button, and then tap on a parcel, Is the parcel highlighted and attribute information displayed on the right?

Comment: @RalphDell Yes and yes. Takes a little time, but parcel gets highlighted and I see the info is displayed. Only in ICS Browser in Android Vimicro tablet. In iphone4s Safari I see no buttons at all. So, what is your point here? Thanks again

Comment: Well I am lost as to why your attempts are not working on mobile devices. The above link uses OpenLayers 2.12 and the wms is served through geoserver. the Identify code is what I posted for GetFeature. I am out of suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the TouchNavigation?
http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/TouchNavigation-js.html

*If you're only targeting touch enabled devices with your mapping application, you can create a map with only a TouchNavigation control.  The OpenLayers.Control.Navigation control is mobile ready by default, but you can generate a smaller build of the library by only including this touch navigation control if you aren’t concerned about mouse interaction.*

It should replace the common Navigation control which comes by default on the map.

OpenLayers should detect the device and add the touch or the normal navigation control depending on the platform you are, but this sometimes doesn't work. And also, sometimes we override this on our code without noticing.

I know it says that normal Navigation control should work on mobile, but on my experience, sometimes it does not work right.

Comment: First : TouchNavigation is only to browse the map or works with vector layers too? -- Second : You mean add this `<script type='text/javascript' src='TouchNavigation.js'></script>` ? I have done this and nothing. Unless you mean add this AND use the control like `var select_feature_control = new OpenLayers.Control.TouchNavigation`. In that case, should I use `Control.TouchNavigation` and `Control.SelectFeature` together? How I should edit/rewrite my code? Thanks a million

Comment: TouchNavigation is already on the general OpenLayers.js file, so you don't need to add any external file.

Can you check what controls do you have enabled on your map? Look on map.controls on your javascript debugger.

Comment: Also, check if this example works on your touchscreen:
http://gis.ibbeck.de/OLClient/examples/WFSGetFeatureControl/WFS_GetFeatureControl.asp

Comment: I add just `map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom({position: new OpenLayers.Pixel(2, 15)}));
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.TouchNavigation({dragPanOptions: {enableKinetic: true}}));` and nothing! Still cannot tap features! My tablet says that the link maybe temp. down or moved to a new web address

Answer (score 1):

Mobile devices require touch controls.

For mobiles, the best is OpenLayers.mobile.js, but since you are using geoserver i guess you are using WFS. The mobile version may not support that. Although the main OpenLayers.js should incorporate touch controls, it does not seem so. add OpenLayers.mobile.js after OpenLayers.js and it should work.

Comment: You mean add `<script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.mobile.js'></script>` after `<script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>`? Because this breaks my search form, for some reason.

Comment: yes, you can even add it before.

Comment: Adding it before does not break the search form. But the points still not get selected.

Comment: You will need a custom build of openlayers which will incorporate both of the files. see http://docs.openlayers.org/library/deploying.html

Comment: To test, I incude just the `openlayers.mobile.js` an breaks the form, even in mobile. Is that normal?

Comment: In mobile, the available space was problem but the form didn't break. What exactly do you mean by break?

Comment: I have an html form. Javascript gathers data from that form's fields. Creates and executes a CQL filter. Form never gets actually submitted. All this happens in one file. If I add `openlayers.mobile.js` and use the form, reloads the page. No results. In URL a `#` appears at the end. As it tries to submit the form? idk....

Comment: The mobile build doesnot include CQL format. You need to add lib\OpenLayers\Format.js and lib\OpenLayers\Format\CQL.js after OpenLayers.mobile.js

Comment: Still no luck. I put `lib\OpenLayers\Format.js and lib\OpenLayers\Format\CQL.js` Or copy those files to the htdocs where OpenLayers.js is and I put in my code just `Format.js and CQL.js`. Either way : form does not break, but cannot tap on points. Maybe I should load another file?

Comment: I added more info in my original question. Maybe will help you spot the error...Thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

With OpenLayers 2.12 I use the Control.GetFeature with a Identify tool and the touch works for me on mobile devices. By that I mean I activate the control, a button, tap the screen and get my results. Let me know if you are able to get that working.

```
ctrl_identify = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
  protocol: myprotocol,
  click: true,
  maxFeatures: 5,
  clickTolerance: 0,
  box: false,
  hover: false
});
```

Here is the more complete code that I have for my GetFeature. I have tried to be careful with my cutting and pasting but it is possible I have introduced a error. The protocol points to a geoserver wms layer. When the control is active and I click or tap on a feature I zoom to it. The feature selected event, not shown, is where I do other useful stuff. As I said in the comments this may or may not help you.

```
myprotocol = {
  version: "1.1.0",
  srsName: "EPSG:900913",
  url: geoserver_url/wms,
  featurePrefix: i use my geoserver workspace,
  featureNS: my_namespace,
  setFeatureType: my geoserver layer,
  geometryName: "geom"
};

filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
  type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
  property: "field",
  value: value
});

selLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("parcel_vector", {
  strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
  styleMap: not shown,
  filter: filter,
  protocol: protocol
});

ctrl_identify = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
  protocol: myprotocol,
  click: true,
  maxFeatures: 5,
  clickTolerance: 0,
  box: false,
  hover: false
});

var my_filter = "field='" + some value + "'";
filter.value = my_filter;   
selLayer.refresh();
```

Comment: I am sorry, can you be more analytical, I did not get  you. How can I replace my `SelectFeature`with `GetFeature`?

Comment: I was not sure how to answer your question so I pulled a couple of OpenLayers examples, on my ipad, that use the SelectFeature Control http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/highlight-feature.html and http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html. They worked on the mobile device. So I am not sure why yours does not. My GetFeature works on vector layer derived from a geoserver WMS layer with a cql filter. Do you want more information in that?

Comment: Let me rephrase. How to edit my code so I can use `Control.GetFeature` instead of `Control.SelectFeature`? Also...Can I use `Control.GetFeature` with vector layers? Will  need a proxy for that?

Comment: I have posted more complete code for my GetFeature. That may or may not help you. I am suspicious about how you are creating your vector layer since the OpenLayers SelectFeature examples work on mobile devices. I use a proxy.

Comment: This is what I do to create my vector layer `mylayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("my layer", {renderers: ["Canvas", "SVG", "VML"]})` Is something wrong with that?

Comment: I added more info to my question. Maybe it will help you spot the error. Thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

Openstreet has support for touch events. See below code :

```
    PlotMarker(map, pt.icon, pt.coor[0], pt.coor[1], true, function(mk) {
        markers.addMarker(mk);
        mk.events.on({
            mouseover: function(ev) {
               alert("Mouse Over Event");         
            },                
            click: function(ev){                   
                alert("Click Event");                  
            },
            touchstart: function(ev){                
                alert("Touch Event");                      
            }
        });
    });
```

`touchstart` simply recognises all touch events and this works in mobiles and tablets. Ive used this in my recent project.

Comment: I use vector layer and features , not Openstreet or markers. Anyway, I tried to use `touchstart:function(e)` in the callbacks of the vector layer, and still nothing.